# Glyph origin of 郵

Tags: glyph-origin

Almost every site I seen tell me that this is a phono-semantic character, but it always uses the simplified form 邮, which is pretty obvious that 由 is phonetic. But what about 郵? 垂 has no phonetic relevance, and I can't seem to find any semantic link to "post" and "mail".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

| 時期 字體 | 字形 | 參考資料 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [秦](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qin_dynasty) [簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboo_and_wooden_slips) | [image] | 10.3 [睡虎地秦簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuihudi_Qin_bamboo_texts) |
| [東漢](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_dynasty#Eastern_Han) [隸](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clerical_script) | [image] | 夏承碑 |
| [楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script) | [image: 郵] |  |

> #### [《說文・邑部》](https://ctext.org/library.pl?if=gb&file=77390&page=85)
>
> <kbd>[image]</kbd>
>
> 境上行書舍。从邑、垂。垂，邊也。

「郵」 is comprised of semantic 「垂」 (*far-away lands; frontier*, now written as 「陲」) and semantic 「邑」 (*city*), indicating the meaning *frontier dispatch station for books/scrolls/letters* (post office).